# Linear Regression for different sample selection

Tags: r, regression

I have edited the following reproducible data frame (DF) which  is taken from stackoverflow user G. Grothendieck.

```
Lines <- "Ctry  year   Carx   Brx
A    2000    13     12
A    2001     8     16
A    2002    12     20
A    2003    16     18
A    2004    10     25
A    2005    13     12
B    2000    20     22
B    2001    24     20
B    2002    32     14
B    2003    32     24
B    2004    30     18
B    2005    36     14   
C    2000    42     36
C    2001    46     25
C    2002    45     32
C    2003    56     38
C    2004    56     15
C    2005    58     60
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

I want to make a regression estimation based on the samples selected by the codes indicated below.

```
subset(DF, (Carx < 15 & year==2005), select=c(Ctry, year, Carx))

DF$class <- "low"

for(i in seq(15,25, by=5)) {

for( j in seq(35,45, by=5)) {

test <- subset(DF, (Carx < i & year==2005), select=c(Ctry, year, Carx))
for (k in unique(test$Ctry)) DF[DF$Ctry==k,"class"]<-"low"

test <- subset(DF, (Carx < j & Carx > i & year==2005), select=c(Ctry,year, Carx))
for (k in unique(test$Ctry)) DF[DF$Ctry==k,"class"]<-"middle"

test <- subset(DF, (Carx > j & year==2005), select=c(Ctry, year, Carx))
for (k in unique(test$Ctry)) DF[DF$Ctry==k,"class"]<-"high"
 }
}
```

The regression equation that I want to estimate is;

```
require(lme4)
est.1 <- lmer(Carx~1+year+(1+year|Ctry), data=DF,REML=F)
```

My problem is that, I want to input the sample selections that is produced by the above codes into the regression equation. If I correctly write the codes, for each i and j, I will obtain a different sample of data. I want to get regression result for each sample.

thanks for help...

Comment: It's a little frustrating that you haven't incorporated the information conveyed in the comments and duplicated question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850507/divide-a-series-into-subclasses , which would make your code much cleaner / easier to read ...

Comment: Sorry, but I took the comment into account. Unfortunately, I could not able to solve my problem. It is not what I am trying to do. Since the post < stackoverflow.com/questions/23850507/divide-a-series-into-subclasses>  was not clear enough, I deleted it. and I have thought that the previous post was removed from site. Due to that reason, I have send new clear post with a reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just a subset of your data to fit a model, you can use the `subset=` parameter

```
est.1 <- lmer(Carx~1+year+(1+year|Ctry), data=DF,REML=F, subset=class=="low")
```

To look at just the records where `class=="low"`. However it looks like in your test data that `class` and `Ctry` are perfectly correlated so you wouldn't be able to do estimates for `Ctry` since all those values are fixed for a given class.